# Union insert SQL trick

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I have a table "accounts" with "org_id" and "account_number" - just two unique identifiers where the latter can be also NULL.

In our app, I need to be able to "find or create" a record in this table without transaction because this operation is done many times. I came up with the following solution:

```sql
WITH insert_and_select AS (
        INSERT INTO accounts (org_id, account_number) VALUES ($1, $2)
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE org_id=$1
UNION
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE $2 IS NOT NULL AND account_number=$2
UNION
SELECT * FROM insert_and_select
UNION
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE org_id=$1
UNION
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE $2 IS NOT NULL AND account_number=$2
LIMIT 1;
```

But I now saw an error from our production PostgreSQL: `no rows in result set` meaning there was a case when this query returned no rows. The input data was: org_id=12345 and account_number was NULL.

How can that be? The only explanation is that two concurrent requests attempted to create new account record, one succeeded but the one that had an (ignored) insert conflict failed to insert the record but the next select statement also failed to fetch it.

Is it possible that two concurrent PostgreSQL sessions would not see each other's data? Is there maybe a better solution to my problem?

Comment: It is not only possible it is the default behavior. See [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that you want to perform this operation without a transaction: **that is not possible**. Every SQL command operates within a transaction, even if `START TRANSACTION` isn't explicitly used. A command issued outside of an open transaction initiates a new transaction that is automatically closed when the command completes.

The failure mode of returning no rows in the result set when an insert encounters a conflict using the described approach is due to read consistency. Every select within the query sees the data either as it was at the time the query started or as modified by the query. For example, if query Q1 starts, but before it completes, query Q2 inserts and commits a conflicting row, then Q1's `ON CONFLICT` clause will be triggered by the conflict, but Q1 won't be able to see the data that caused the conflict.

A solution is to requery the data whenever an empty result set is returned, but be prepared to handle another empty result set since it's possible that another query deleted the conflicting row between the attempted insert and the  requery.